# Is it possible to move an object closer or farther away while keeping the same perspective?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

If I grab an object and move it left or right, or up-and-down, it moves in a path perpendicular to my current view. Is it possible to move an object parallel to my current view?

In other words, I want the object to move closer or farther away while maintaining the same relative position in my view.

Is this capability built into to blender?

Comment: could you please add screenshots of your problem to explain what you mean to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you ask yes, it's possible, switch to view transform orientation then grab the object and press ZZ (constrain the grab on view Z axis):

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks for the clear, concise, and quick answer!